# Table Sorting Trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is my view code :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myTable").tablesorter();
    });

</script>
    <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Date Debut
        </th>
        <th>
            Date Fin
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%: item.Dd.ToShortDateString() %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: item.Df.ToShortDateString() %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Supprime", "DeleteInd", new { id=item.idind }) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% } %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Also i have added in my master page those to script :

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'm trying to allow sorting table, so i used the jquery script all ready found [on this website](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Introduction) but it doesn't work ? i think i have missed something very simple but i can't figure it :(

and here is the generated code :

```
 <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.core.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#dd").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
            $("#df").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
            $("#dd1").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
            $("#df1").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
        });
    </script> 
</head>
  <body>
// html code
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myTable").tablesorter();
    });
</script>
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="main">
        <h1> List des Vehicule</h1>    
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Date Debut
        </th>
        <th>
            Date Fin
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            01/04/2012
        </td>
        <td>
            26/04/2012
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/Agence/DeleteInd/2">Supprime</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            01/05/2012
        </td>
        <td>
            09/05/2012
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/Agence/DeleteInd/3">Supprime</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
 </div>
```

When i click on the Js link it show me the file code so it's generated

Comment: Can you please show the rendered code instead of your code that generates the code?  That said, it looks like you're probably not loading your JS files properly.  View Source and try to click on the javascript files in the source listing to see if they're there.

Comment: I have update it check it please :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `jquery-latest.js` is a version of jQuery, you should include that in your page first. Also, it's best practice to use Google's CDN to load jQuery. Try this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```